# Shift Array Members Up One Level and SUM Values of Matching Keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I have this array of data:

```
array (size=3)
  123 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string '50000.00' (length=8)
  126 => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => string '20000.00' (length=8)
  86 => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => string '6000.00' (length=7)
```

Im and trying to move each sub array up one level and SUM the totals if the keys match. For instance the result should look like this:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => string '50000.00' (length=8)
  3 => string '26000.00' (length=8)
```

I have tried:

```
foreach ($weight_arr as $value)
 {
   $new_arr += $value;
 }
```

But end up with:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => string '50000.00' (length=8)
  3 => string '20000.00' (length=8)
```

I have tried of a few other solutons but were all failures. I must be missing something, this seems like such a simple thing to do.

EDIT:

Original Data:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => int 17
      'wo_id' => int 12
      'prod_id' => int 123
      'qty' => int 3
      'cat_id' => int 12
      'blend' => null
      'length' => null
      'lbs' => string '50000.00' (length=8)
      'delay' => null
      'unit' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-06-12 14:15:10' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-06-12 14:15:10' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'product_id' => int 123
      'truck_types_id' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => int 18
      'wo_id' => int 12
      'prod_id' => int 123
      'qty' => int 3
      'cat_id' => int 12
      'blend' => null
      'length' => null
      'lbs' => string '50000.00' (length=8)
      'delay' => null
      'unit' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-06-12 14:15:10' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-06-12 14:15:10' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'product_id' => int 123
      'truck_types_id' => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => int 19
      'wo_id' => int 12
      'prod_id' => int 126
      'qty' => int 2
      'cat_id' => int 12
      'blend' => null
      'length' => null
      'lbs' => string '20000.00' (length=8)
      'delay' => null
      'unit' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-06-14 23:28:25' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-06-14 23:28:25' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'product_id' => int 126
      'truck_types_id' => int 2
  3 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => int 20
      'wo_id' => int 12
      'prod_id' => int 126
      'qty' => int 2
      'cat_id' => int 12
      'blend' => null
      'length' => null
      'lbs' => string '20000.00' (length=8)
      'delay' => null
      'unit' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-06-14 23:28:25' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-06-14 23:28:25' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'product_id' => int 126
      'truck_types_id' => int 3
  4 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => int 12
      'wo_id' => int 12
      'prod_id' => int 86
      'qty' => int 25
      'cat_id' => int 11
      'blend' => null
      'length' => null
      'lbs' => string '6000.00' (length=7)
      'delay' => null
      'unit' => null
      'created_at' => string '2016-01-21 00:33:59' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2016-01-21 00:33:59' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'product_id' => int 86
      'truck_types_id' => int 3
  5 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => null
      'wo_id' => int 12
      'prod_id' => int 88
      'qty' => int 15
      'cat_id' => int 11
      'blend' => null
      'length' => null
      'lbs' => null
      'delay' => null
      'unit' => null
      'created_at' => string '2016-01-21 00:33:59' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2016-01-21 00:33:59' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'product_id' => null
      'truck_types_id' => null
  6 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => null
      'wo_id' => int 12
      'prod_id' => int 90
      'qty' => int 10
      'cat_id' => int 11
      'blend' => null
      'length' => null
      'lbs' => null
      'delay' => null
      'unit' => null
      'created_at' => string '2016-01-21 00:33:59' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2016-01-21 00:33:59' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'product_id' => null
      'truck_types_id' => null
```

And foreach that creates array im working with:

```
foreach($prodArr as $prod)
 {
  if(!is_null($prod['lbs']))
    if(empty($weight_arr[$prod['truck_types_id']])) $weight_arr[$prod['prod_id']] = array($prod['truck_types_id'] => $prod['lbs'] );
 }
```

Comment: Show outer `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not posted your whole code, I have just rewritten it from scratch as I understood your assignment. Please comment, if I misunderstood something there...

```
<?php

$a = [
    123 => [1 => '50000.00'],
    126 => [3 => '20000.00'],
    86 => [3 => '6000.00']
    ];
var_export($a); 

$na = [];

foreach ($a as $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $na)) $na[$key] += $value;
        else $na[$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_export($na);
```

Note that it might be a good idea to use [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) for working with floats instead of strings there, although PHP handle that quite well and the above code without using floats just works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
  123 => 
    [ 1 => '50000.00' ],
  126 => 
    [ 3 => '20000.00' ],
  86 => 
    [ 3 => '6000.00'  ]
];
$decimals = '.';
$thousands = '';

$new = array();

foreach($arr as $firstlevel) {
    foreach($firstlevel as $key => $val) {

        /* Since we have strings representing floats we need to 
         * transform them into float first and transform them
         * back to their string after adding them together
         */
        if(isset($new[$key])) {
            $new[$key] = number_format( 
                floatval($new[$key]) + floatval($val), 
                2, 
                $decimals, 
                $thousands
            );

        } else {
            $new[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new);
echo '</pre>';
```

If you need exactly that string format, read about `number_format()` and `floatval()` in the php documentation. To solve your problem you need to use to foreach loops. The first going over every element of your array, the second going over every element of every subarray.